# Is image processing impacted by the lens or sensor size of the camera?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-recognition, detection, visual-tracking

We want to configure a system for detecting and tracking basketball shots made. We have control over the cameras, so we can choose anything from a smartphone to a GoPro.

1. Assume the scene is a typical high school gym. For the purposes of object detection and tracking, is it better for image processing to use an iPhone 7 or a GoPro (which has a larger sensor)?
2. Would a single camera with a wide HFOV (e.g., GoPro) allow for faster image processing than a camera like the iPhone 7 with a narrow HFOV?
3. Would a stereo system accelerate ball detection and tracking, or would the costs of stereo calibration outweigh the benefits of depth data? 
   [This paper from 1999](http://www.ai.sri.com/~beymer/vsam/iccv99.pdf) studies the benefits of stereo vision, but it seems like it's likely outdated now.

Answer (score 1):

> Is image processing impacted by the lens or sensor size of the camera?

Yes, since both affect the image that is processed. That was easy :)

> For the purposes of object detection and tracking, does it matter if the images being processed came from a camera with a large sensor (e.g., DSLR) or a small sensor (e.g., smartphone)?

Sensor sizes have different effects on the image. You might want to read about these. As a rule of thumb, the larger the sensor, the less noisy the image. That makes everything easier. Thus, at least for a design/prototyping phase, I'd at least use a good camera with a high resolution and most importantly: a very well-lit scene!

2) Yes. I mean, what did you expect. Bad lens -> distorted image. Distorted image -> more problems.

3) well. This is like asking "would a second car make moving from A to B easier?" and the answer is "yes, but it depends on how much of what you need to move across which terrain".

Seriously, you're asking the strangest questions. Maybe get an idea for the kind of system you want to build before picking sensors.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Sorry, maybe the question should be reworded. To clarify, if you're taking recording in a typical high school gym, is it better to use an iPhone 7 versus a GoPro?

Comment: Sorry again for the ambiguous questions. Updated the question to make them more specific. Could you elaborate on how #3 should be made more specific?

Comment: Seriously, I explained what's wrong with your question –  there's no "better" or worse generally. It depends on *what* you want to do. And you don't seem to have an idea of what you *want* to do. Therefore, you might as well be filming with a sharpened herring.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. As explained in the question, the goal is to do shot detection on a basketball court. Is that not specific enough?

Comment: No. Goal is to move sand. What is better: wheelbarrow or big bucket? The answer will always remain: depends on what you're trying to do, exactly. There's no inherent optimal system for object tracking, because it all depends on what kind of object tracking you're trying to implement. And I explained the advantages of larger sensor in my answer.

Comment: OK, will try to narrow question further, but some guidance would be helpful. The goal is to detect when a shot is made and automatically cut a 5-second video of the area 30 feet in the front of the hoop. Is that specific enough? The shot detection would ideally occur in real-time, but can occur with a 60-second latency.

Comment: No. As said, you're still trying to answer the last qeustions first. Decide on an object tracking methodology, then decide on the sensors. Not the other way around. I can't really tell you how to detect specific sports moves – that sounds like a very complex task and would require modelling of what you want to detect **first**, which can only be done by someone who knows what *you* know.